# making unique combinations from the given characters

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there any algorithm available for this one :

From a group of characters like :

```
a,@,n,M,O,f,D,),`,~,;,N,*,8,2,],2........ goes one . There are about 92 characters
```

Now I have to make unique combinations from these 92 characters of certain length *(could be 5,3,2,10)* until a certain condition is met.

Like a combination of 3 characters from 92 could be like :

```
abc
@82
)~N
......
```

Is there any algorithm available for this or I have device my own algorithm?

Comment: Do you want all permutations of 92 chars? There are `92! ~= 1.24*10^142` of those. Probably more then the number of atoms in the milky way.

Comment: @amit I really don't know how did you _count_ (!) the **atoms** in the milky way

Comment: I didn't, it is just a rough prediction, since 1.24*10^142 is such a huge number. I am not a physicist, I could be wrong - but nevertheless, assuming you can process 1 trillion permutations per second (very optimistic), you will need 3.94*10^122 **years** to find all permutations. I doubt you (or earth) have that much time.

Comment: @amit rephrased the question.

Comment: There are "92 choose k" = `92!/(k!(92-k)!)` possible combinations of `k` such characters (with `0<=k<=92`, of course). That can still get very large, especially if `k` is close to 41. (A Google search for "92 choose 41" gives an answer of `2.397127e+26`.)

Comment: @JackManey It will surely get large. But I need an algorithm.

Comment: Well, without loss of generality, you may as well be generating `k` element subsets of {1,2,...,92}. Proceed lexicographically.

Comment: I don't think you actually answered the request for clarification: Do you actually need _all_ permutations, or do you just want X unique permutations of a specific length, using these specific characters? The latter is a very different request.

Comment: @Kjartan  X unique permutations of a specific length

Comment: Wait: do you need combinations or permutations? Those are different things.

Comment: @JackManey combinations. The question was edited by someone

Comment: @JackManey edited the question back to original

Comment: guys he just wants to randomly generate these until he meets a certain condition, not to generate all of them

Comment: @amit:  Actually he said "combinations", that's *only* 2^92.  :-D

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Quite the opposite. If you really want *combination* and not *permutation* there are `92^length` of those. There are 2^92 *subsets*.

Comment: @amit: no, `92^length` is not combinations. for a smaller example: if you have `abcde`, `aaaaa` is not a valid combination. you have `92 C 1 + 92 C 2 + 92 C 3 + ... + 92 C 91 + 92 C 92` possibilities.

Comment: @Claudiu That depends if you do it with or without repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

First be aware that the number of possible permutations is in `O(n^k)` (`Choose(n,k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)` to be exact) where `n` is the number of characters and `k` is the desired length. Since it is exponential it could easily grow out of reach.

A general algorithm for achieving these combinations is using recursion and explore all possibilites up to this length. At each level you "guess" which character you will use next, place it, remove it from the list of available chars and recurse to solve the smaller problem (finding permutation up to `length-1`).

```
private static void printPermutations(char[] chars, int idx, List<Character> candidate, int length) {
    if (length == candidate.size()) { 
        System.out.println(candidate);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = idx; i < chars.length; i++) {
        candidate.add(chars[i]);
        //set the selected element out of reach:
        char temp = chars[idx];
        chars[idx] = chars[i];
        chars[i] = temp;
        //recurse:
        printPermutations(chars, idx+1, candidate, length);
        //clean up environment:
        temp = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[idx];
        chars[idx]  = temp;
        candidate.remove(candidate.size()-1);
    }
}
public static void printPermutations(char[] chars, int length) { 
    printPermutations(chars, 0, new LinkedList<Character>(), length);
}
```

Comment: There are 92! permutations. Surely you meant O(n!). If it contains repeats it's not a permutation.

Comment: @HerpDerpington: `O(n!)` is in `O(n^n)`. Note I never claimed it to be `Theta`. It is a simplification, the more bounded complexity is what I denoted later as *to be exact*

Comment: Not sure why you want to obfuscate the strict bound with n^k.

Comment: @HerpDerpington: Simplicity. I think it is more important that readers will understand it is growing fast then understanding *exactly* how fast (I added a notation for those who want *exactly*) and I believe some non-expereinced readers might get confused when reading `O(n!/(k!*(n-k)!)`, while `O(n^k)` is simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Here is a working python version of combinations without repetitions:

```
def ncombs(n,k):
    if n < 0 or k < 0 or k > n: return 0
    b = 1
    for i in xrange(k): b = b*(n-i)/(i+1)
    return b

def nthresh(k, idx):
    """Finds the largest value m such that C(m, k) <= idx."""
    mk = k
    while ncombs(mk, k) <= idx:
        mk += 1
    return mk - 1

def rank_to_comb(k, rank):
    ret = []
    for i in range(k, 0, -1):
        element = nthresh(i, rank)
        ret.insert(0, element)
        rank -= ncombs(element, i)
    return ret

def random_combination(choices, n):
    num_combinations = ncombs(len(choices), n)
    desired_rank = random.randint(0, num_combinations-1)
    indices = idx_to_set(n, desired_rank)
    return [choices[i] for i in indices]
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['b', 'd', 'h']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['b', 'd', 'g']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['d', 'f', 'i']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['d', 'f', 'h']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['b', 'c', 'e']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['c', 'i', 'l']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['c', 'g', 'j']
>>> random_combination("abcdefghijkl", 3)
['b', 'j', 'l']
```

It works by generating the rank of the desired combination, then generating the combination from the rank, then using that to index into the list of choices. By doing so you guarantee an even distribution of indices (so you don't generate any one combination more often than others).

For example, if you wanted to choose 5 elements from a list of 10, there are `10 C 5` = `252` possible combinations. The first combination is `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, the second is `(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)`, the third is `(0, 1, 2, 4, 5)`, etc... The `rank_to_comb` function accomplishes the translation:

```
>>> rank_to_comb(5, 0)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> rank_to_comb(5, 1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> rank_to_comb(5, 2)
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> rank_to_comb(5, 250)
[4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> rank_to_comb(5, 251)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So we just uniformly pick a number from 0 to 251, get the combination, index into the choices list, and we're done!

---

This is the old version that generated permutations, not combinations:

Here is how to generate one combination:

```
public static String comboFrom(String possibleChars, int charsToTake) {
    //randomly shuffle the chars using Collections.shuffle
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(possibleChars.length());
    for (char c : possibleChars.toCharArray()) {
        chars.add(new Character(c));
    }

    Collections.shuffle(chars);

    //Take the first 'charsToTake' characters - these will be totally random
    //thanks to the shuffle
    String result = ""; 
    int taken=0;
    for (Character c : chars) {
        result += c.charValue();
        if (taken >= charsToTake) break;
        taken += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
for (int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
    System.out.println(comboFrom("abcdefghijkl@#%", 5));
}
```

Resulted in:

```
ecjlaf
bi@hfj
ia@#e%
icfad@
kb#gei
ik%@de
ib%jkf
flgb@#
gd@ekc
jedhi#
f@%ckj
lig%#j
l%fki#
ajgdlc
adkbe@
gb@cid
#efcag
@lihkc
k@j%#c
cgkaji
ecb@hj
k@lf%a
gd%fbh
c%lajf
e@#cid
%gfeb#
#%ahcf
be@flj
albjk@
calh%g
```

You can just call this function repeatedly and stop when you get a result that satisfies your needs. Here is [the full code I used](http://ideone.com/42ahh).

EDIT: And sorry for this plug but this was so much more annoying to do than I thought that I'm glad I'm using Python at my job:

```
import random
def comboFrom(possibleChars, charsToTake):
    chars = list(possibleChars)
    random.shuffle(chars)
    return "".join(chars[:charsToTake])
```

Comment: actually this won't work because it results in permutations, not combinations. will have to think how to do combinations neatly.