# What algorithms/methods are used to employ a brute force method?

Tags: java, algorithm

While reading [making unique combinations from the given characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275253/making-unique-combinations-from-the-given-characters) on SO , I was wondering if is this the technique the programs the use *Brute-Force* method apply ? I mean making 92 combinations to break a userID or a password. A typical windows keyboard has some 92 characters that can be used in a password.

I am not asking how to break a password by this method but wanted to know what method do some sophisticated programs use for a *Brute-Force* method ?

Comment: Note that the denoted question asked for *permutation* - there, a certain character cannot repeat, which is not a standard restriction for passwords.

Comment: Maybe you should read about [Dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). Note, I'm not promoting this kind of attack, just providing an example of Brute Force algorithm.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza dictionary attack is different from brute force attack. I guess it will never be able to tell a password that could be _ZuntenableZ_ (untenable). will it ?

Answer (score 3):

The Naive way to solve problems using brute force is indeed a simple [**backtracking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), which explore all possibilities, evaluates them, and chose the best.

However, for some problems - you might have more information then "It solves it" or "It doesn't solve it". For example, for the [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) problem (Finding if a boolean formula has a solution) - you can get knowledge on "how exactly did you get the contradiction" (Which variables could not be satisfied with the assignment). Usually we refer this issue as **Constraint Propogation**. It is applied for SAT under the [**DPLL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) algorithm which is often used (in variations) for SAT solvers.

If you are interested - real life programs that use SAT solvers are various, [Software verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_verification) algorithms are one example that use SAT solvers in order to *prove* a software (or more commonly hardware) is working as it should.

Another common optimization is [**Branch and Bound**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) - meaning, you can trim your "search tree" before you reach the leaves. An example will be for [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). If you already found a path of length 100, and you are exploring a new one, and reached 101, no need to keep exploring this possibility.