# Java security checking

Tags: java, security, passwords

I'm trying to make an application in Java to check my password security.
This is what I already did:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BruteForce {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "123123";
        char[] charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
        BruteForce bf = new BruteForce(charset, 1);

        String attempt = bf.toString();

        while (true) {

            if (attempt.equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("Password Found: " + attempt);
                break;
            }

            attempt = bf.toString();
            System.out.println("" + attempt);
            bf.increment();
        }
    }

    private char[] cs; // Character Set
    private char[] cg; // Current Guess

    public BruteForce(char[] characterSet, int guessLength) {
        cs = characterSet;
        cg = new char[guessLength];
        Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
    }

    public void increment() {
        int index = cg.length - 1;

        while(index >= 0) {
            if (cg[index] == cs[cs.length-1]) {

                if (index == 0) {
                    cg = new char[cg.length+1];
                    Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    cg[index] = cs[0];
                    index--;
                }
            }
            else {
                cg[index] = cs[Arrays.binarySearch(cs, cg[index]) + 1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(cg);
    }
}
```

But I take a long time to get the "123123" as password (Maybe I don't even get it, I'm not sure)...
Is there a better method to do this with upper/lower alphabetical letters and numbers? Thank you.

Comment: 1) your code is a very big eye sore. 2) Yeah a long time isn't 30 minutes a long time is billion's of years. Your password sucks if it can be brute forced  at all...

Comment: okay, I already thought it. How can I fix? (123123 is a test). Some advises?

Comment: You should definately fix the coding convention you have here. The indentations are not present making your code very hard to read...

Comment: Fix what nothing is broken ? You want it to take longer just make your password longer. Include special characters

Comment: You code doesn't take very long at all for me to run.  I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` almost immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What algorithms/methods are used to employ a brute force method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275880/what-algorithms-methods-are-used-to-employ-a-brute-force-method)

Comment: The code could be optimized quite a bit.
I'd recommend googling or reading more about brute force attacks as well

Comment: The problem is that, when I bruteforce "123123" I do it in many minutes. I take less time if I bruteforce "test". The code should go fine?
@azurefrog / Sir Troll can you explain?

Comment: Define some rules for a good password (e.g. length, mix of characters, digits and special characters, ...) and check your password against that.

Comment: Ok. I will follow your advise. Thanks .. @azurefrog what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if I copy your code into eclipse and run it, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -62` almost immediately.

Comment: I don't have any idea what is the real problem, because I don't use Eclipse but NetBeans, what is supposed to be that? @azurefrog

Comment: Your `charset` array isn't sorted according to the natural ordering of `char`.  [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-char:A-char-) says that it **"Searches the specified array of chars for the specified value using the binary search algorithm. The array must be sorted (as by the sort(char[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined."**, and in my case, that result is a crash.

Comment: You have `charset` defined as `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, but after a `Arrays.sort(charset);` it would be `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: Okay! I fixed it to 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Thank you.